# Asynchronous methods in Java/Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, tomcat, asynchronous

I don't want to use a thread runnable in order to execute 2 parallel jobs on my tomcat server (for example: send notification and email). I came a cross with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ib9diRjXjxo) tutorial. I have added a `javax.ejb` dependency to my pom.xml, but still there is no `@Asynchronous` annotation available.

I am not sure that it's even suppose to work on my tomcat 7.0 server. Is it? if so what is wrong? [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/ejb-api/3.0) is the link to the maven dependency.

Comment: So you basically want to tell Tomcat to do two other things in the background while it continues to serve requests?

Comment: my use case, is that the server get some request from client app (then the servlet handles it), and for this request I want to do 2 unrelated operations: send email and notification.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a thread with a Runnable? Generally, you should submit to an ExecutorService which internally manages the threads. Does your server app want to return immediately or block until the tasks are completed.

Comment: It also depends on the rest of your stack. I've done Java REST services with Jersey, deployed to Tomcat. That has an async API so you can have a long running request running that doesn't tie up a server thread.

Comment: Anyway that kind of jobs will be run on threads, in some case they will be threads from EJB thread pool, they also may be thread from scheduler or some task management framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Tomcat does not support EJBs. Therefore, the easiest solution is to create a Executor using the Executors class, store it as a static variable in your servlet, and submit tasks to it as Runnables.

Comment: totally agree, needs to replace Tomcat with JBoss, GlassfFish or other full stack JEE Server.

Comment: Personally, I see no need to switch to using EJB instead of Executors (which should work just fine for this use case), but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Usually JEE guidelines prevent from using threads, which sometimes may be cause of instability and memory leaks.

Comment: Alright. I've never actually done what I suggested, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: @chro, in this case the user which is waiting for the response of his request will have to wait while unrelated process will be finished running one after another instead of them running on deferent threads (in order to cut the process time)?

Comment: No, as far as I am aware, it should handle asynchronously and not hold up the user.

Comment: There is no way to do asynchronous activity without using threads of some type. Whether you use them yourself, or have a library handle it is up to you.

Comment: @JohmDon so can I use the Executor class in tomcat 7?

Answer (score 0):

You include dependency on the EJB version 3.0, but the @Asynchronous annotation is avaliable only since EJB version 3.1.

Lets try to change version from 3.0 to the 3.1

Comment: can you give me the hole maven dependancy? I am getting an error when changing 3.0 to 3.1

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't it. At general, you try to add a dependency on EJB API. The problem is tomcat isn't application server and it doesn't support JEE and haven't EJB container (implementation), so you application wouldn't work at the server even you find out a dependency to the EJB 3.1 api. The only I can suggest it's try to change tomcat to an application server. Maybe openEJB will be a good choice for you (http://openejb.apache.org/documentation.html)